# PHP - form with confirm screen and image upload

Tags: php, forms, file-upload, confirmation

I am stuck in making a form with PHP that has a confirm screen and a field for uploading an image. The idea is to fill the form and upload the file in the input screen, being able to go to the confirm screen where I can see my content (including the file name) and also be able to go back to the input screen to choose another file if we wished (On that time I need to still be able to see my file name). Finally from the confirm screen if I hit send I get my content registered in a CSV file (for the image I need to register the path of the file)

except for the upload, I managed to finish everything.
for the upload, i understand I need to upload to a temp file then move it to a folder then if back to input file I need to show the info of the temp file if the user submits I need to copy it to another folder.

I understand the above but I couldn't realize it, I did the part of uploading to a temp file then move it to a folder I just can't get the info of the temp file once back to the input screen and Also I couldn't copy it to another folder when the user submits the form.

Here is my code, I use three files index.php and lib/send.php and complete.html
Some words are written in Japanese But it's not important.

Someone, please guide me to accomplish this task.

```
    <?php
    mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

    require("./lib/send.php");
    $sendForm = new SendForm();

    $mode = "";

    $name_sei = "";
    $name_mei = "";
    $email = "";
    $sex = "1";
    $birth_year = "";
    $birth_month = "";
    $birth_day = "";
    $image = "";
    $comments = "";

    $error_msg = array();
    //vdd($_POST['mode']);
    if (isset($_POST['mode']) && ($_POST['mode'] == 'back' || $_POST['mode'] == 'confirm' || $_POST['mode'] == 'complete')) {
        $mode = $_POST['mode'];
        //vdd($mode);

        $error_num = 0;

        $data = $sendForm->checkPostData();
        //vdd($data);

        $name_sei = $data['input_data']['name_sei'];
        $name_mei = $data['input_data']['name_mei'];
        $email = $data['input_data']['email'];
        $sex = $data['input_data']['sex'];
        $birth_year = $data['input_data']['birth_year'];
        $birth_month = $data['input_data']['birth_month'];
        $birth_day = $data['input_data']['birth_day'];
        $image = $data['input_data']['image'];
        //vdd($image);
        $comments = $data['input_data']['comments'];

        if ($data['error_num'] > 0 && $mode != 'back') {
            $mode = "error";
            $error_msg = $data['error_msg'];
        }

        if ($mode == "complete") {

            $sendForm->send($data['input_data']);
        }
    }

    if ($mode != "confirm" && $mode != "complete") {

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>お問い合わせ</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>お問い合わせ</h1>
    <h2>入力画面</h2>

    <form action="./index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="confirm">

    <div class="formBox">


        <div>
            <label for="name"><span class="req">*</span>名前:</label>
            <input class="name_input" type="text" name="name_sei" value="<?php echo $name_sei; ?>" placeholder="山田">&nbsp;<input class="name_input" type="text" name="name_mei" value="<?php echo $name_mei; ?>" placeholder="太郎">
            <?php
            if (isset($error_msg['name'])) {
                echo "<br><span class=\"alert\">{$error_msg['name']}</span>\n";
            }
            ?>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="email"><span class="req">*</span>メールアドレス:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>" placeholder="yourmail@example.com">
            <?php
                if (isset($error_msg['email'])) {
                    echo "<br><span class=\"alert\">{$error_msg['email']}</span>\n";
                }
            ?>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="sex"><span class="req">*</span>性別:</label>
            <input type="radio" class="radio_input" name="sex" value="1"<?php if($sex == 1) echo " checked=\"checked\"" ?>>男性
            <input type="radio" class="radio_input" name="sex" value="2"<?php if($sex == 2) echo " checked=\"checked\"" ?>>女性
            <?php
                if (isset($error_msg['sex'])) {
                    echo "<br><span class=\"alert\">{$error_msg['sex']}</span>\n";
                }
            ?>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="birthday"><span class="req">*</span>生年月日:</label>
            <select name="birth_year">
                <option value="">--</option>
                <?php
                $start_year = 1948;
                $last_year = date("Y");
                for ($i = $start_year; $i <= $last_year; $i++) {
                    $selected = "";
                    if ($i == $birth_year) $selected = " selected=\"selected\"";

                    echo "<option value=\"{$i}\"{$selected}>{$i}</option>\n";
                }
                ?>
            </select>
            年&nbsp;
            <select name="birth_month">
                <option value="">--</option>
                <?php
                for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
                    $selected = "";
                    if ($i == $birth_month) $selected = " selected=\"selected\"";

                    echo "<option value=\"{$i}\"{$selected}>{$i}</option>\n";
                }
                ?>
            </select>
            月&nbsp;
            <select name="birth_day">
                <option value="">--</option>
                <?php
                for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++) {
                    $selected = "";
                    if ($i == $birth_day) $selected = " selected=\"selected\"";

                    echo "<option value=\"{$i}\"{$selected}>{$i}</option>\n";
                }
                ?>
            </select>
            日
            <?php
            if (isset($error_msg['birth'])) {
                echo "<br><span class=\"alert\">{$error_msg['birth']}</span>\n";
            }
            ?>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="file"><span class="req">*</span>プロフィール画像:</label>
            <input type="file" name="image" id="image" value="<?php echo $image;?>"><br><small class="hint">プロフィール画像はJPG,PNGのみで2MBまで</small>
            <?php
                //vdd($image);
                if (isset($error_msg['image'])) {
                    echo "<br><span class=\"alert\">{$error_msg['image']}</span>\n";
                }
            ?>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="comments"><span class="req">*</span>一言コメント</label>
            <textarea name="comments"><?php echo $comments; ?></textarea>
            <?php
                if (isset($error_msg['comments'])) {
                    echo "<br><span class=\"alert\">{$error_msg['comments']}</span>\n";
                }
            ?>
        </div>

        <div class="button">
            <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn-submit">確認する</button>
        </div>

        </div>
    </form>

    </body>
</html>

<?php
    //====================フォームここまで============================//
    } else if ($mode == "confirm") {
    //====================確認画面ここから============================//
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>contact confirm</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function back_form() {
                $('#mode').val('back');
                $('#formConform').submit();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>お問い合わせ</h1>
        <h2>確認画面</h2>


        <form action="index.php" method="POST" id="formConform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="complete" id="mode">


        <input type="hidden" name="name_sei" value="<?php echo $name_sei; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="name_mei" value="<?php echo $name_mei; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="sex" value="<?php echo $sex; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="birth_year" value="<?php echo $birth_year; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="birth_month" value="<?php echo $birth_month; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="birth_day" value="<?php echo $birth_day; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="image" value="<?php echo $image; ?>">
        <?php
        //vdd($image);
        ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="comments" value="<?php echo $comments; ?>">

        <div>
            <table class="form">

                <tr>
                    <th><p><span class="req">*</span>名前</p></th>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $name_sei; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $name_mei; ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th><p><span class="req">*</span>メールアドレス</p></th>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $email; ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th><p><span class="req">*</span>性別</p></th>
                    <td>
                        <?php
                        if ($sex == 1) {
                            echo "男性";
                        } else {
                            echo "女性";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th><p><span class="req">*</span>生年月日</p></th>
                    <td>
                        <?php
                        $year_str = $birth_year;
                        ?>
                        <?php echo $year_str."年 ". $birth_month."月 ".$birth_day."日 ";?>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th><p><span class="req">*</span>プロフィール画像</p></th>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $_FILES['image']['name']; ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <th><p><span class="req">*</span>一言コメント</p></th>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $comments; ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </div>


        <div>
            <div class="return">
                <button type="button" onClick="back_form()">戻る</button>
            </div>
            <div class="send">
                <button type="submit">送信する</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>

<?php
    //====================確認画面ここまで============================//
    }
?>
```

and here is the code in lib/send.php

```
<?php

function vd($data) {
echo "<pre>", var_dump($data), "</pre>";
}
function vdd($data) {
echo "<pre>", var_dump($data), "</pre>";
die;
}

class SendForm {

    function checkPostData() {

        $name_sei = "";
        $name_mei = "";
        $email = "";
        $sex = "1";
        $birth_year = "";
        $birth_month = "";
        $birth_day = "";
        $image = "";
        $comments = "";

        $error_msg = array();
        $error_num = 0;
        $error_birthday_num = 0;
        $uploadOk = 0;

        if (isset($_POST['name_sei'])) {
            $name_sei = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name_sei']));
        }
        if (isset($_POST['name_mei'])) {
            $name_mei = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name_mei']));
        }
        if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
            $email = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
        }
        if (isset($_POST['sex'])) {
            $sex = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['sex']));
        }
        if (isset($_POST['birth_year'])) {
            $birth_year = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['birth_year']));
        }
        if (isset($_POST['birth_month'])) {
            $birth_month = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['birth_month']));
        }
        if (isset($_POST['birth_day'])) {
            $birth_day = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['birth_day']));
        }
        if (isset($_FILES['image'])) {
            $image = ($_FILES['image']);
            //vdd($image);
        }
        if (isset($_POST['comments'])) {
            $comments = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['comments']));
        }


        if ($name_sei == "" || $name_mei == "") {
            $error_msg['name'] = "入力されていません。";
            $error_num++;
        } else if ( (strpos($name_sei, ',') !== false) || ((strpos($name_mei, ',') !== false)) ) {
            $error_msg['name'] = "カンマの使用はできません。";
            $error_num++;
        } else if (mb_strlen($name_sei) > 10 || mb_strlen($name_mei) > 10) {
            $error_msg['name'] = "10文字までで入力してください。";
            $error_num++;
        } 

        if ($email == "") {
            $error_msg['email'] = "入力されていません。";
            $error_num++;
        } else if (!preg_match('|^[0-9a-z_./?-]+@([0-9a-z-]+\.)+[0-9a-z-]+$|', $email)) {
            $error_msg['email'] = "メールアドレスの形式が正しくありません。";
            $error_num++;
        }

        if ($birth_year == "" || $birth_month == "" || $birth_day == "") {
            $error_msg['birth'] = "生年月日が正しく選択されていません。";
            $error_num++;
        } else if ((!is_numeric($birth_year) || $birth_year < 1948 || $birth_year > date("Y") || $birth_year != round($birth_year)) || (!is_numeric($birth_month) || $birth_month < 1 || $birth_month > 12 || $birth_month != round($birth_month)) || (!is_numeric($birth_day) || $birth_day < 1 || $birth_day > 31 || $birth_day != round($birth_day))) {
            $error_msg['birth'] = "生年月日が選択幅に含まれていません。";
            $error_num++;
        } else if (checkdate($birth_month, $birth_day, $birth_year) == false) {
            $error_msg['birth'] = "日付は存在しません。";
            $error_num++;
        }

        function file_check($fileName) {

        $check_result = mime_content_type($fileName);
            if ( ($check_result == "image/png") || ($check_result == "image/jpeg") || ($check_result == "image/jpg") ) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (isset($_FILES['image'])) {
            $target_dir = "uploads/";
            $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
            $uploadOk = 1;
            $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        }
        // Check if the file is sent via post
        if(isset($_FILES["image"])) {
            if ($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]!== "") {
                if($imageFileType == "jpg" || $imageFileType == "png" || $imageFileType == "jpeg") {
                    if ($_FILES["image"]["size"] < 2097152) {
                        if (file_check($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]) == true) {
                            $uploadOk = 1;
                        } else {
                            $error_msg['image'] = "File is not an image or has an incorrect extension.";
                            $uploadOk = 0;
                            $error_num++;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $error_msg['image'] = "Your file is too large. ";
                        $uploadOk = 0;
                        $error_num++;
                    }
                } else {
                    $error_msg['image'] = "Only JPG, JPEG & PNG files are allowed. ";
                    $uploadOk = 0;
                    $error_num++;
                }
            } else {
                $error_msg['image'] = "You need to upload a file first. ";
                $uploadOk = 0;
                $error_num++;
            }

            if ($uploadOk == 0) {
                echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
            } else {
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["image"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
                } else {
                    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
                }
            }
        }

        if ($comments == "") {
            $error_msg['comments'] = "入力されていません。";
            $error_num++;
        } else if (mb_strlen($comments) > 200) {
            $error_msg['comments'] = "200文字までで入力してください。";
            $error_num++;
        } 

        $input_data = array();
        //vdd($input_data);

        //vdd($image);
        $input_data['name_sei'] = $name_sei;
        $input_data['name_mei'] = $name_mei;
        $input_data['email'] = $email;
        $input_data['sex'] = $sex;
        $input_data['birth_year'] = $birth_year;
        $input_data['birth_month'] = $birth_month;
        $input_data['birth_day'] = $birth_day;
        //vdd($_FILES['image']);
        $input_data['image'] = $image;
        //vdd($input_data['image']);
        $input_data['comments'] = $comments;


        // vdd($input_data);
        return array('input_data' => $input_data, 'error_num' => $error_num, 'error_msg' => $error_msg);

    }

    // 送信
    function send($data) {
        mb_language("uni");
        mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
        $name_sei = $data['name_sei'];
        $name_mei = $data['name_mei'];
        $email = $data['email'];
        $sex = $data['sex'];
        $birth_year = $data['birth_year'];
        $birth_month = $data['birth_month'];
        $birth_day = $data['birth_day'];
        $image = $data['image'];
        //vdd($image);
        $comments = $data['comments'];

        $sex_str = "";
        if ($sex == 1) {
            $sex_str = "男性";
        } else {
            $sex_str = "女性";
        }

        $name_str = $name_sei . "　" . $name_mei;

        $year_str = $birth_year;

        $birth_day_str = $year_str."年 " .$birth_month."月 ".$birth_day."日";

        // converting to suit csv function
        function convertToSuitCSV($html) {
            $needle = '"';
            $lastPos = 0;
            $positions = array();

            while (($lastPos = strpos($html, $needle, $lastPos))!== false) {
                $positions[] = $lastPos;
                $lastPos = $lastPos + strlen($needle);
            }

            for ($i = count($positions) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
                $html = substr_replace($html, '"', $positions[$i], 0);
            }
            return '"'.$html.'"';
        }

        // csv

        $header = array('名前', 'メールアドレス', '性別', '生年月日', '登録時間', '一言コメント');
        function encode_items($arrayToEncode) {
            foreach($arrayToEncode as $key => $value) {
                $arrayToEncode[$key] = mb_convert_encoding($value, "SJIS", "UTF-8");
            }
            return $arrayToEncode;
        }

        $header_encoded = encode_items($header);

        $today = date("Ymd");
        $register_time = date("Y-m-d H:i");
        $comments = htmlspecialchars_decode($comments);
        $comments_suited = convertToSuitCSV($comments);

        $csvData ="{$name_str},{$email},{$sex_str},{$birth_day_str},{$register_time},{$comments_suited}";

        $csvData = mb_convert_encoding($csvData, "SJIS", "UTF-8");
        $csvData = htmlspecialchars_decode($csvData);

        $file = fopen("{$today}.csv","a");  

        if (filesize("{$today}.csv") == 0){
            fputcsv($file, $header_encoded);

            if($file) {
                fwrite($file,$csvData."\n"); 
                fclose($file);
            }
        } else {
            if($file) {
                fwrite($file,$csvData."\n"); 
                fclose($file);
            }   
        }

        // ありがとう画面へ遷移させる
            $redirect_path = "./complete.html";
            header("Location: {$redirect_path}");

        exit;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: The temp file only exists for the duration of one script. You'll have to move the file out into your own temp folder, and store the variable in a session (or pass it back to the next form).

Comment: I want to perform it without the use of sessions
Can you show me how to pass it back because I use different modes

Comment: When you output the form for the second page, add `<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $myTempFile; ?>" />` and pass the value from the first page to the second. Be sure to sanitize the input, so that malicious users can't modify the value of the hidden input to point to other files on your server. My suggestion would be to ensure that `$myTempFile` is only a filename (And not a path to a file), and sanitize it using [`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) to strip out any paths on the return form submission.

Comment: Thank you for this info, I will try it